# Spring REST Docs - fieldWithPath in Junit Test

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I have a Spring Boot v1.5.14.RELEASE app., Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat and following the RESTful API architecture principes. I have created this test

```
@Test
    public void createCustomerChain() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/customer/createCustomer")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .content("{\n" +
                        "   \"subSegment\":\"25\",\n" +
                        "   \"legalLanguage\":\"NL\",\n" +
                        "   \"isRestrictel\":true,\n" +
                        "   \"isCommunicationLanguageForAllAccount\":true,\n" +
                        "   \"isAntiMarketing\":true,\n" +
                        "   \"hotelChain\":{\n" +
                        "       \"legalForm\":\"09\",\n" +
                        "       \"foundationDate\":\"2001-12-17T09:30:47Z\",\n" +
                        "       \"tradingName\":\"COMPANY NAME\",\n" +
                        "       \"printName\":\"TEST PRINT\",\n" +
                        "       \"naceCode\":\"16230\",\n" +
                        "       \"vatNumber\":\"41223334343\",  \n" +
                        "       \"countryVatCode\":\"IN\",\n" +
                        "       \"isSubjectToVAT\":true,\n" +
                        "       \"sectorCode\":\"85\",\n" +
                        "       \"legalAddress\": {\n" +
                        "           \"mainkey\":2088512,\n" +
                        "           \"subkey\":3256\n" +
                        "       }\n" +
                        "   },\n" +
                        "   \"isVATNumberOnBill\":true,\n" +
                        "   \"communicationLanguage\":\"EN\"\n" +
                        "}"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(document("customer-create-request-Chain",
                        preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                        preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                        responseFields(
                                fieldWithPath("billingAccountId").description("The billing account id of the newly created customer"),
                                fieldWithPath("paymentAgreementId").description("The Payment Agreement Id of the newly created customer"),
                                fieldWithPath("customerId").description("The id of the new created customer"),
                                fieldWithPath("isNewlyCreated").description("Set to `true` when the customer is newly created")),
                        requestFields(
                                fieldWithPath("subSegment").description("Market subsegment"),
                                fieldWithPath("legalLanguage").description("Legal language"),
                                fieldWithPath("isAntiMarketing").description("If true, customer does not want to have any marketing contact"),
                                fieldWithPath("isRestrictel").description("Indicates that the customer is on the orange list. Do not disclose information to other companies for commercial purposes."),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.legalAddress.mainkey").description("LAM mainkey of the address. If the mainkey and the subkey is given the rest of the address information is not needed."),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.legalAddress.subkey").description("LAM subkey of the address"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.legalForm").description("Legal form"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.foundationDate").description("Date of the foundation of a company(mandatory field for 'Chain' customer type)"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.vatNumber").description("Enterprise or VAT number"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.countryVatCode").description("ISO2 country code of the VAT number"),
                                fieldWithPath("isVATNumberOnBill").description("Indicates if the VAT number will be shown on the bill"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.isSubjectToVAT").description("Indicates if the enterprise number is a real VAT or not"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.sectorCode").description("Subtitle Description. Additional information relating to the customer. Name-Value pairs"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.tradingName").description("Trading name"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.printName").description("Print name of the customer"),
                                fieldWithPath("hotelChain.naceCode").description("Nace code"),
                                fieldWithPath("communicationLanguage").description("Communication language"),
                                fieldWithPath("isCommunicationLanguageForAllAccount")
                                        .description("If true, commercial language of all BGC billing accounts receive the value defined at customer level and users not allowed to change commercial language of any billing account"))));
    }
```

and this is the result of running the test:

```
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: Fields with the following paths were not found in the payload: [customerId]
```

and removing the `customerId` from `fieldWithPath` test passed successfully but, I wonder why I don't have the same error for such a field like `billingAccountId`

Comment: Would you kindly show the response? I can only guess that - as the console tells - the field `customerId` is missing while the others are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `customerId` field could be `null` or absent in some cases. You can use `optional` for it:

```
fieldWithPath("customerId").description("Description").optional()
```

To find a more precise reason, please, post the code of the `createCustomer()` method.